# Firebase offline data-inconsistencies

Tags: android, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

### Database structure

```
 {
    "places": {
        "<push-key>": {
            "name": "Company X"
        },
        "<push-key>": {
            "name": "Restaurant Y"
        }
    }
    "users": {
        "<push-key>": {
            "name": "Harry"
        }
    },
    "userPlaces": {
        "<user-push-key>": {
            "<place-push-key>": {
                "name": "Company X"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

We are working on an application in where users can add places to their account. We've denormalized the database. So that we have faster reading requests (and easier filtering and sorting). But now we've come accross the problem when a user is working offline, they can add cached places to their account.

But if the name of the place is changed while the user is offline, the cached version and the real-time version are not in sync anymore. Wat happens is that the app writes a place to the userPlaces node, with the old place data.

This causes data-inconsistencies. Is there any fix for this problem?

## Edit

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("userPlaces/" + userId + "/" + mPlace.getKey(), place);
update.put("placeUsers/" + mPlace.getKey() + "/" + userId, user);
reference.updateChildren(update);
```

The data is given to firebase. And firebase updates the values when it gets online.

Comment: This depends on how you synchronize the data. Please (for this and future questions) share the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've added a small code snippet

Comment: If you're asking what happens when two clients update the same location with conflicting updates, the last write wins in that case. If you want more control, use transactions. But transactions don't survive app restarts, so that limits where you can use them.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: We've used a structure where the userPlaces and placeUsers do not contain the place object, but only the key. So basically we've chosen to not duplicate the data.